# How do I get a transparent part of a image texture to show up as transparent instead of black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I'm making a Minecraft Steve Rig that supports 1.8 skins (2 layers) and when I try to texture the second layer, the area of the 2nd layer's UV texture that is clear (has no texture) comes out black.
How do I get it so that the Clear part of the texture comes out clear so you can see the first layer?

[image: model and texture in blender]